# How to open desktop application by javascript

Tags: javascript, windows

I want to know how steam and other websites opens desktop application by web page

[image: Steam example]

I find a similar example in microsoft support
[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-default-browser-in-windows-10-020c58c6-7d77-797a-b74e-8f07946c5db6#:~:text=Select%20the%20Start%20button%2C%20and,Microsoft%20Edge%20or%20another%20browser](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-default-browser-in-windows-10-020c58c6-7d77-797a-b74e-8f07946c5db6#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20Start%20button%2C%20and,Microsoft%20Edge%20or%20another%20browser).
[image]

How does work?